# In next js next auth I am using callbacks and async session to run a post request. But I only want to do it with GoogleProvider and not with other

Tags: authentication, next.js

This is my nextauth file :

```
const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID?? '',
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET?? ''
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name : "Credentials",
      async authorize(credentials, req){
        try {
          const response = await axios.post(
            process.env.API_ROUTE,
            { email: credentials.email, password:  credentials.password, apiKey:  process.env.API_KEY },
            {
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
              },
            }
          );
          const userData = response.data;
          return { success: true };
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Login failed:", error);
          return { success: false };
        }
      }
  })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({token, account}) {
      if (account) {
        token = Object.assign({}, token, { access_token: account.access_token, id_token: account.id_token,  refresh_token: account.refresh_token });
      }
      return token
    },
    async session({session, token}) {
    if(session) {
      session = Object.assign({}, session, {access_token: token.access_token, id_token: token.id_token})
      try {
        const  apiKey = process.env.API_KEY
        const response = await axios.post(
          process.env.GOOGLE_API,
          {  authorizationCode: token.id_token, apiKey: apiKey },
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
          }
        );
        const userData = response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed:", error);
      }
      }
    return session
    },
  }
})

export {handler as GET, handler as POST};
```

Now the code inside the session callback where I am making a post request is something that I only want to do when logging in with google and not with credentials. So how can I do that?

The code runs fine I am able to connect with the api and get all the tokens with CredentialProviders but it fails to properly login as it also tries to run that post request inside session that should only run when logging in with google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider to store the provider information in the session when the user logs in and then use that information to decide whether to perform the post request. You can use the account.provider property to check which provider was used during authentication.

```js
async session({ session, token }) {
    if (session.provider === "google") {
      //...conditionally execute logic here
    }

    return session
}
```

Alternatively you can use a custom property within the token to indicate the provider.

```js
async jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
    if (account?.provider) {
      token.provider = account.provider
    }
    // ... your existing code ...

    return token;
},
async session({ session, token }) {
    if (token.provider === "google") {
      //...conditionally execute logic here
    }
    return session
}
```